# Precedência em Query JPA

Tags: java, jpa, repository

Eu estou usando a notação `@Where(clause = "ts_removed is null")` em minha entidade.
Se eu inserir um método com `@Query(value = "XXX")` no meu repositório, a query irá sobrescrever ou irá usar a minha cláusula where inserida na entidade também no repositório?

Answer (score 0):

> a query irá sobrescrever ou irá usar a minha cláusula where inserida na entidade também no repositório

A cláusula do `@Where` inserida na entidade também será usada no repositório.

Por isto, recomendo evitar ao máximo usar o `@Where`. Uma vez que tiver o caso onde precisará não usar ela, você precisará refatorar a aplicação para acomodar esta mudança.

Você tem três alternativas: **@Filter**, **SQL nativo** ou **mapear um campo novo**.

O **@Filter** [funciona](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) de maneira similar ao `@Where`, mas você determina quando usar. O problema é que ela precisa ser habilitada na sessão do Hibernate, o que pode ser algo bem verboso ou trabalhoso com o Spring.

Exemplo com Spring:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.enableFilter("tsRemovido"); // se não habilitar, a condição será ignorada na consulta
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entidade e");
//resto do código
```

Entidade:

```
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="tsRemovido", condition="ts_removed is null")
} )
public class Entidade {
```

Já com **SQL nativo**, [ele pode ser invocado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962006/2387977) usando o `@Query` com o atributo `nativeQuery = true`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entidade e", nativeQuery = true)
```

Porém, ao usar SQL nativo, você não terá a comodidade de usar a entidade do Hibernate para receber as informações.

Se quiser **mapear um campo novo**, [você pode criar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522871/2387977) um novo mapeamento para a coluna que está envolvida na cláusula `@Where` mas usando outro nome. Na sua consulta, você passa a usar esta nova coluna e não a coluna que está no `@Where`:

```
@Column(name = "ts_removed") // usado pelo @Where
private Date tsRemovido;

@Column(name = "ts_removed", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private Date tsRemovidoSemWhere;
```